# 'Add XY Coordinate' operation failure upon Feature Class file-type; using ArcMap 10.8.2 & ArcCatalog 10.8.2

Tags: arcmap, coordinates, feature-class, error-999999, append

I am working with feature class (FC) files, which are of counties from North Carolina (US State), stored in an ESRI gdb. Using the tool 'Add XY Coordinates' I have attempted to append and populate POINT_X & POINT_Y fields to each FC.  The tool has worked before during this project (I attached images of this), but upon recent county FCs 'Add XY...' has failed.  In one instance the Results data from the Geoprocessing menu gave an error of "Class not registered", but with later attempts it has not given a specific error.  The first two images are for Alleghany county, and the last is for Beaufort county.
The files each have an appropriate coordinate system assigned.  They all have pairs of fields containing StatePlane and DDLatLong coordinates. The error message image is from Catalog, and shows up the same in ArcMap.

What can be done to solve this issue?

[image: First image: StatePlane & DDlatLong fields in FeatureClass table]

[image: Second image: as part of the table from first image, added POINT_X-POINT_Y fields and values]

[image: Example of message from Results (via Geoprocessing menu)]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you explore the following:

1. Do you have an environment setting like Extent causing the tool to fail as the extent is outside the dataset extent?
2. For your Beaufort dataset, view it in ArcMap, do you see the points that should be there in the correct location?
3. Run the check geometry tool on that layer, does it have any errors?
4. If the data has come from some other source such as an SQL database, have spatial indices been created? You can confirm that by looking at the feature class properties.
5. Are the layers compressed, causing the tool to fail? Again you confirm that by the feature class properties.
6. Consider running the update feature class extent tool?